# I have faceing responsive issue

Tags: iphone

Hello i'm faceing resposive issue on Iphone mobile devices there my some css property not working both browser chrome and safari. Is there anybody can help me. I link some screenshot you can see that.

[This is iphone device screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cos0l.jpg)

[This is android device screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5eIY.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "faceing responsive." It is unclear which CSS properties you're having trouble with. As Mat notes, you need to provide sufficient information to help us help you. If you already knew the answer, and someone else asked this question, would you be able to answer it just from the text given?

Comment: Hi Rob Napier i'm type here website link if you have iphone you can check it your mobile. http://csinfotech.co.in/rainbow/